# Rotating an entire circle composed of individual arcs/sectors

Tags: eclipse, processing

Okay, so I've been trying to program a game for an APCS class and I have been using Processing.org/PApplet for the graphics. My main image is an ellipse composed of individual arcs that have different colors. However, I would like to rotate the entire circle (with the arcs inside). Here is the code that I have for this:

```
public void setup() { 
         size(WIDTH, HEIGHT); background(22, 105, 250); 
} 

public void draw() { 
         drawLevel(level,18); 
}

private void drawLevel(int level, int numSectors) 

{   

        translate(50, -50);
        rotate((float)PI*level/numSectors);
        fill(255,0,0);
        arc(500, 375, 500, 500, 0, (TWO_PI)/18);


        rotate((float)PI*level/numSectors);
        translate(50, -50);
        fill(255,127,0);
        arc(500, 375, 500, 500, (TWO_PI)/18, (TWO_PI*2)/18);

        //rotate((float)PI*level/numSectors);
        //translate(50, -50);
        fill(255,255,0);
        arc(500, 375, 500, 500, (TWO_PI*2)/18, (TWO_PI*3)/18);

        //rotate((float)PI*level/numSectors);
        //translate(50, -50);
        fill(0,255,0);
        arc(500, 375, 500, 500, (TWO_PI*3)/18, (TWO_PI*4)/18);

        //rotate((float)PI*level/numSectors);
        //translate(50, -50);
        fill(0,0,255);
        arc(500, 375, 500, 500, (TWO_PI*4)/18, (TWO_PI*5)/18);

        //rotate((float)PI*level/numSectors);
        //translate(50, -50);
        fill(75,0,130);
        arc(500, 375, 500, 500, (TWO_PI*5)/18, (TWO_PI*6)/18);

        //rotate((float)PI*level/numSectors);
        //translate(50, -50);
        fill(139,0,255);
        arc(500, 375, 500, 500, (TWO_PI*6)/18, (TWO_PI*7)/18);

        //rotate((float)PI*level/numSectors);
        //translate(50, -50);
        fill(255,0,0);
        arc(500, 375, 500, 500, (TWO_PI*7)/18, (TWO_PI*8)/18);

        //rotate((float)PI*level/numSectors);
        //translate(50, -50);
        fill(255,127,0);
        arc(500, 375, 500, 500, (TWO_PI*8)/18, (TWO_PI*9)/18);

        //rotate((float)PI*level/numSectors);
        //translate(50, -50);
        fill(255,255,0);
        arc(500, 375, 500, 500, (TWO_PI*9)/18, (TWO_PI*10)/18);

        //rotate((float)PI*level/numSectors);
        //translate(50, -50);
        fill(0,255,0);
        arc(500, 375, 500, 500, (TWO_PI*10)/18, (TWO_PI*11)/18);

        //rotate((float)PI*level/numSectors);
        //translate(50, -50);
        fill(0,0,255);
        arc(500, 375, 500, 500, (TWO_PI*11)/18, (TWO_PI*12)/18);

        //rotate((float)PI*level/numSectors);
        //translate(50, -50);
        fill(75,0,130);
        arc(500, 375, 500, 500, (TWO_PI*12)/18, (TWO_PI*13)/18);

        //rotate((float)PI*level/numSectors);
        //translate(50, -50);
        fill(139,0,255);
        arc(500, 375, 500, 500, (TWO_PI*13)/18, (TWO_PI*14)/18);

        //rotate((float)PI*level/numSectors);
        //translate(50, -50);
        fill(255,0,0);
        arc(500, 375, 500, 500, (TWO_PI*14)/18, (TWO_PI*15)/18);

        //rotate((float)PI*level/numSectors);
        //translate(50, -50);
        fill(255,127,0);
        arc(500, 375, 500, 500, (TWO_PI*15)/18, (TWO_PI*16)/18);

        //rotate((float)PI*level/numSectors);
        //translate(50, -50);
        fill(255,255,0);
        arc(500, 375, 500, 500, (TWO_PI*16)/18, (TWO_PI*17)/18);

        //rotate((float)PI*level/numSectors);
        //translate(50, -50);
        fill(0,255,0);
        arc(500, 375, 500, 500, (TWO_PI*17)/18, (TWO_PI*18)/18);

}
```

I have the translations and rotations as comments but I'm not sure how to rotate the entire thing. When I run the `translate()` and `rotate()` method, it only runs once (which should happen), but when I try to use it for the second arc, it overlaps the first arc and it centers itself off very weirdly. Can someone help with the loop that is required for "animating" it and looping it and how to change the `rotate()` and `translate()` method? Please and thank you!

Comment: The first translate and rotate method works perfectly, so my question is how to keep the circle rotating and how to make the other instances of the translate and rotate method work for the other arcs.

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]? In other words, can you post your `setup()` and `draw()` functions?

Comment: Yes here is my setup() method:
public void setup() 
 { 

  size(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  background(22, 105, 250);

 }

Comment: And here is my draw() method:

public void draw() 
 {
  drawLevel(level,18);
 }

Comment: Also, sorry for my formatting, this is my first time here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start out with a simpler example:

```
void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  drawCircle();
}

void drawCircle() {
  fill(255, 0, 0);
  arc(width/2, height/2, 500, 500, radians(0), radians(180));

  fill(0, 0, 255);
  arc(width/2, height/2, 500, 500, radians(180), radians(360));
}
```

Now that we have that, we can talk about rotating the circle. There are two main ways to do this.

**Option 1:** Rely on the `translate()` and `rotate()` functions to do the rotation for you.

Note that if you do it this way, you either need to translate, rotate, **and then untranslate**, or you need to draw everything at the origin.

Here is using the translate, rotate, untranslate approach:

```
void drawCircle() {

  translate(width/2, height/2);
  rotate(TWO_PI*mouseX/width);
  translate(-width/2, -height/2);

  fill(255, 0, 0);
  arc(width/2, height/2, 500, 500, radians(0), radians(180));

  fill(0, 0, 255);
  arc(width/2, height/2, 500, 500, radians(180), radians(360));
}
```

Note that in this case I'm translating to the center of the circle, then doing my rotate, then translating back to the upper-left corner before I draw the circle. **Your code doesn't do this**, which I think is one of your main problems.

And here is using the origin approach:

```
void drawCircle() {

  translate(width/2, height/2);
  rotate(TWO_PI*mouseX/width);

  fill(255, 0, 0);
  arc(0, 0, 500, 500, radians(0), radians(180));

  fill(0, 0, 255);
  arc(0, 0, 500, 500, radians(180), radians(360));
}
```

Note that in this case, I'm drawing my arcs at the origin. But since I'm **not** untranslating, that origin is in the center of the screen.

Your code seems to be a mix of these approaches, which is why it isn't working. Also note that if you want to rotate the circle, **you only need one call to `rotate()`.** It doesn't make sense to rotate every single arc, since you're already calculating their rotations (your math involving `TWO_PI`).

**Option 2:** Instead of using `translate()` and `rotate()`, you can keep track of the rotation yourself. This is especially easy since you're already passing in angles to the `arc()` function.

Here is that approach:

```
void drawCircle() {

  float startAngle = 360 * mouseX / width;

  fill(255, 0, 0);
  arc(width/2, height/2, 500, 500, radians(startAngle), radians(startAngle+180));

  fill(0, 0, 255);
  arc(width/2, height/2, 500, 500, radians(startAngle+180), radians(startAngle+360));
}
```

Notice that I no longer have to fuss with `rotate()` or `translate()`, since I'm calculating the rotation myself.

Which approach you take really depends on what fits in your head the best. But your current code seems to be a weird mix of several approaches, which is why it's not working.

Comment: Thank you sir! This really helps!

Comment: Now, after this, would I be able to use a for or a while loop to keep it rotating? I'm not sure how I would incorporate a loop into here.

Comment: what?! no points? do you want also to grade your paper and give you an A??

Comment: @rick.chat Sure. My example uses `mouseX`, but you could use any variable, and then increment it howerver you want. Try using `frameCount` in my example instead of `mouseX`.

Comment: @gpasch I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. Who are you talking to?

Comment: @KevinWorkman, I tried it out and it works (after changing the variables around). Thank you, for you're a lifesaver!!!

Comment: @rick.chat No problem. If this answer helped you, feel free to upvote and accept it. Gotta get those sweet internet points :p